# Align image in middle (vertical) of a div with css

Tags: html, css

I could use some help, aligning images (different sizes) at the middle of a container div. Have made a picture where you can see the div (the gray background) and that the images should align in the middle.

[image]

As you see, if the images are different in size, it will not look nice. How can I align all the images in the middle (vertical) so they are inline?

I'm not sure I can use position: absolute because I still want the images to resize itself (height: auto & width: 100%).

**Html:**

```
<div class="window column border small-12 medium-6 large-4 xlarge-3" *ngFor="#item of items">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="item-group">
                    <span>Fri fragt!</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column small-12">
                    <div class="item-imagegroup">
                        <img src={{item.Image}} title="" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column small-12">
                    <div class="item-descriptiongroup">
                        <div class="item-header">{{item.Header}}</div>
                        <div class="item-description">{{item.Description}}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column small-12">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column small-6">

                </div>
                <div class="column small-6">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.item-imagegroup {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: grey;
    vertical-align: middle; 
}

.item-imagegroup img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.item-image {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;     
}
```

Have made the div fixed, so the text under also will be aligned. Not sure if there is a better solution here.

Hope someone can give me some advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vertical-align works only with tables
try to make a wrap div and give it "display: table;"
and to the div that wrap the img give: "display: table-cell"

Don't forget to make all of it 100% width&height

EDIT:

HTML:

```
<div class="item-imagegroup">
    <div class="item-tablecell">
        <img src={{item.Image}} title="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.item-imagegroup {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: grey;
}

.item-tablecell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Not sure I follow you... you mean I should make wrap it in another div and giv it display: table?

Comment: Thanks for your help man.. appreciate.

Answer (score 3):

You could try

```
.element {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

This should work, assuming you aren't looking for legacy support.

Source: http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/